# InappBrowser _blank issue

Tags: android, cordova

I am loading an url (developed using PHP) using inappBrowser with '_blank' property. Its loading well. But I am not able to open the image gallery from that loaded url. please give me any solution. My code is here.

```
window.open(urlpath, '_blank', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Which Version do you use?
- For which OS do you develop? (iOS, Android, etc.)
- You can not use serverside languages like php
- What exactly is the error message you get?
- How should we help you with this **few** information from you?